Monitor's refresh rate drops to 60hz when certain windows are focused
In windows display settings or intel graphics command center, the refresh rate of my monitor is set to 120hz. However, when certain application's window get focus, the entire screen's refresh rate drops to 60hz, which is noticeable by mouse cursor moves.
I know that there is an issue with Windows Presentation Foundation (https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/2294), and my monitor is Variable Refresh Rate capable, but I have disabled that in intel graphics command center.
Also, the issue occurs when all the applications are minimized and only the background wallpaper is being shown. When certain "modern" application windows is un-minimized, the refresh rate goes up to 120hz again.
When a Firefox browser windows is focused, and the browser is displaying mostly static contents, the refresh rate drops to 60hz; When some animation kicks in in the webpage, the refresh rate goes up to 120hz.
When some 'modern' application windows is opened, and when I move mouse cursors above that app window, the refresh rate is 120hz. When the mouse cursor leaves the window, the refresh rate drops to 60hz.
This is extremely annoying, yet I could not find a setting that governs this behavior. How do I fix my monitor's refresh rate at 120hz?
